# Laravel 5.5 - Call the backgroud services

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am new in laravel and want to call the background service in Laravel 5.5, like I used to call in Codeigniter using `exec()` function and command inside that.

I tried with the following code:

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('email:send', [
        'user' => 1, '--queue' => 'default'
    ]);
});
```

Comment: In Laravel you have Jobs, Queue and Dispatcher. First you need to setup the driver( I'd go for database), then create the job that you want to add to the queue and then dispatch that job in the controller. Notice that you need to have `php artisan queue:listen` in order for this to work.

For more information, read https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues

Comment: What do you mean by "background service"?

Comment: @NicoHaase I mean I used to execute the command "php path for function in controller" using exec() in codeigniter so I am not able to find how this will happen in Laravel

Comment: @StfKolev Thanks for reply Let me try this

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?